# Finding the most efficient way to parse a string with a known format into an array of objects in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have a `string` with the format:

```
let names = "Name1: Info1 and Name2: Info2 and Name3: Info3"
```

What is the most efficient method to translate it into an `array` of `objects` following this interface:

```
interface Name {
    name: string;
    info: string;
}
```

Comment: Define "efficient". Anyway, a regex would work (iterate/map the result).. also a split on `' and '` and then (looping through the result) `': '`, perhaps. Or can Info1 be something like `"Notice: Hello and goodbye world!"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way would probably be to write a custom parser, but if you just want quick and dirty:

```js
console.log(
"Name1: Info1 and Name2: Info2 and Name3: Info3"
.split(' and ')
.map(i => i.split(': '))
.map(i => ({name: i[0], info: i[1]}))
)
```